# Why is the file in gulp not copied to the selected path

Tags: gulp

I used this structure to test

```
const gulp = require('gulp');


gulp.task('clone', function() {
return gulp.src('TEST/index.html')
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
 });
```

Gulp/TEST/index.html
Gulp/public/copying here takes a long time
Gulp/gulpfile.js

the task is running, but nothing happens

C:\Users\alesh\OneDrive\Working stol[SuperSliv.biz][ItProger] Processing of the full stack by the developer\Gulp>cloning gulp [21:25:32] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Desktop[SuperSliv.biz ][ItProger] Loading the full stack of developer\Gulp\gulpfile.js [21:25:32] Starting "cloning"... [21:25:32] The "cloning" is completed after 11 ms

I tried to use the base along the way, but still nothing

```
const gulp = require('gulp');


gulp.task('clone', function() {
return gulp.src(['TEST/index.html'], {base: 'TEST'}
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
 });
```

Comment: You have a space at the end of `'TEST/index.html '` - get rid of it and see if it works.

Comment: Я исправил на то что вы указали и все равно не работает

Comment: Is the path you are trying to copy relative to the location of your `gulpfile.js`?  So maybe `./TEST/index.html` is the correct relative path.